# TreeView in Html / Angular

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, nested, treeview

I am trying to create something similar to a tree view in HTML and I am using angular. My current issue is the normal Select statement will only go one layer deep on Parent-Child relations as well as you cannot select the optGroups or rename them. An example of the code would be like this:

```
ID | ParentID | Name
 1 |   NULL   | Building A              Building A
 2 |     1    | Room 1                      Room 1
 3 |     1    | Room 2                          Closet 1
 4 |     2    | Closet 1                    Room 2
 5 |   NULL   | Building B              Building B
```

With this example, I would like to be able to select any of the values on the right as the consumer and return the corresponding ID related to the selection.

Edit:
To further explain my question, I guess what I am specifically looking for would be a TreeView inside of a combobox like shown in 
[This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syt9S.png) to be used in a table.

The table structure that I will be using to fill this combobox would be very similar to the demo shown above, which would be a list of Locations with the details of an ID, an optional parentID, and a Name.

Any suggestions on how to create this would be fantastic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate your question here? Any code you can share to guide?  I think I may be able to help, I have recently build a hierarchy tree similar to what you are asking, but I am not sure exactly what you need.

Comment: What I am looking for is either a combobox that would house a treeview for the user to select the value they want or something similar that would work with a table.  I have tried using the Select statement with GroupBy, but that only allows one tier of heirarchy (unlike a treeview) and you cannot select the groups as options, which I want.